# Is religion "entirely" absent in the Harry Potter series?

Tags: harry-potter, religion

I don't recall anything directly related to religion having been mentioned in the books from **Philosopher's Stone** to **Half-Blood Prince** (1-6). 
The only exception is that Christmas is widely celebrated. In **Deathly Hallows** Harry and Hermione pass St Jerome's Church in Godric's Hollow and there's one biblical reference ([source](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/16792/70951)):

> in Harry Potter and the Deathy Hallows, Harry finds two tombstones
>   with Bible (New Testament) quotes on them. His parents' reads "The
>   last enemy that shall be destroyed is death" (1 Corinthians 15:26)
>   while Kendra and Ariana Dumbledore's reads "Where your treasure is,
>   there will your heart be also" (Matthew 6:21).

Two direct references in all seven books (and potentially **Harry Potter and the Cursed Child**), is this correct?

Comment: @Valorum: Not exactly a duplicate of that question, I am aware of the existence of the question though and used an answer as reference. Practicing religion and religion in general are different matters.

Comment: The presence and practice of religion in a fictional work are synonymous.