# With what religion is St. Mungo affiliated?

Tags: harry-potter

<del>I doubt that St. Mungo is a Christian saint.</del> (Proven wrong by [Jason Baker](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/156430/with-what-religion-is-st-mungo-affiliated#comment408189_156430).) If not, is there a religion associated with St. Mungo, or is it an affectation to name it in a similar way to Muggle hospitals?

Comment: Nobody tell Glasgow. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saint_Mungo

Comment: Related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/16058/are-there-practiced-religions-in-the-wizarding-world?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Typically speaking, "saint" is either Orthodox or Roman Catholic (why do you doubt that he is a Christian saint?). Prior to the Great Schism in 1054, there's no distinction, and any saint is a saint to both. Given the 1600s timeline and the heavily Western point of view in HP, I think it's safe to say that St. Mungo was Roman, though definitely not the St. Mungo of Glasgow who lived in the 6th century.

Answer (score 10):

According to the Harry Potter "[fact file](https://www.pottermore.com/explore-the-story/st-mungos)" on St Mungo's Hospital, it was

> Founded by Healer Mungo Bonham in the 1600s

Which echoes the information found on [JKR's original website](https://web-beta.archive.org/web/20080331191355/http://www.jkrowling.com:80/textonly/en/wotm.cfm) (and which also gives his birth-date and confirms his gender)

> *Wizard of the Month - March 2005:* **Mungo Bonham (1560 - 1659):** Famous wizard healer. Founded
>   St Mungo's Hospital for Magical Maladies and Injuries

No indication is given why Mr Bonham was made a saint or whether this was simply a nickname for someone who devoted his life and considerable wealth to the wellbeing of his fellow wizards.

---

As has been pointed out in comments, there is [another St Mungo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saint_Mungo#Miracles) associated with healing (he resurrected a bird) however this individual died nearly a thousand years prior to Mungo Bonham founding his hospital so it's relatively unlikely that they share an in-universe connection other than a similar first name.

Comment: This [related article](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/2006/08/12/how-did-mungo-bonham-become-a-saint/) asks the same question and draws the same blank.

Comment: It is possible that Mungo Bonham named the hospital after his namesake

Comment: @Valorum - I still feel that quoting Pottermore's paraphrasing is completely pointless when in the presence of the actual canon source it was derived from, and that it definitely shouldn't be on the top of your answer. But then I guess this just boils down to our disagreement on the canon value of the non-Rowling-contributed parts of Pottermore. (grumble grumble.) Well, unlike wiki links, Pottermore links don't stop me from upvoting, so have an upvote I guess. (deleting obsolete comments)

Comment: @ibid - In this case, the Pottermore article offers new information.

Comment: @Valorum - But anything "new" is just a result of poor paraphrasing. I wouldn't be so sure that Mungo waited until after turning 40 to found the hospital.

Comment: The link doesn't work.