# Harry Potter and religion

Tags: harry-potter, religion

Witch hunting was standard practice for muggles of old. One can argue that the main reason was *fear of the unknown*, but it is established (Beedle tales) that one major component of said fear was religious.

How about the other way? Do magic folk follow any religious practices?

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/16058/are-there-practiced-religions-in-the-wizarding-world may be useful to you.

Comment: Odd. accusations of maleficium were prosecuted not only in ecclesiastical courts, but also in secular courts. While you're on to something with "fear of the unknown", human nature being what it is, I suspect the root cause was more like "woe is me, my cow won't give milk ... wait a minute, it must be that old hag who lives down the lane! She's always giving people the evil eye! I bet she did it!!" In any event, what does witch hunting, in historical context, have to do with religion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Possibly.

## The Fat Friar was a wizard and part of the church.

There is no mention of any wizards actually taking part in worship, attending religious ceremonies, or celebrating religious holidays - the closest ever seen is Hogwarts’s secular Christmas festivities. However, Hufflepuff’s house ghost, the Fat Friar, was part of the church when he was alive. He was also undoubtedly a wizard, and attended Hogwarts himself.

> “New students!’ said the Fat Friar, smiling around at them. ‘About to be sorted, I suppose?’
>
> A few people nodded mutely.
>
> ‘Hope to see you in Hufflepuff!’ said the Friar. ‘My old house, you know.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone, Chapter 7 (The Sorting Hat)*</sup></sub>

The Pottermore writing on the Hogwarts ghosts confirms that he was indeed part of the church as well.

> Hufflepuff house is haunted by the Fat Friar, who was executed because senior churchmen grew suspicious of his ability to cure the pox merely by poking peasants with a stick, and his ill-advised habit of pulling rabbits out of the communion cup. 
> <sub><sup>*[- Hogwarts Ghosts (wizardingworld.com)](https://www.wizardingworld.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/hogwarts-ghosts)*</sup></sub>

So, the Fat Friar would indeed have taken part in religious practices.

## Kendra and Ariana Dumbledore’s tomb has a Bible quote.

Additionally, Kendra and Ariana Dumbledore’s tomb has a biblical quote.

> “She pointed to the dark stone. Harry stooped down and saw, upon the frozen, lichen-spotted granite, the words *Kendra Dumbledore* and, a short way below her dates of birth and death, *and her daughter Ariana.* There was also a quotation:
>  
> *Where your treasure is, there will your heart be also.*” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 16 (Godric’s Hollow)*</sup></sub>

Comment: Although it's more likely that the Fat Friar was executed because his ability to heal people would have made him a hero in the common people's eyes, making him a threat to the senior churchmen's authority.